# add datatable pass as parameter in postgresql

Tags: c#, postgresql

I want to pass datatable from c# as parameter to postgress function. But I have no idea. How it is posible. If any ideas please share example for it. Please thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a type on sql. This type will match with your DataTable. Now you can pass your DataTable as structured type in your C# code.

Comment: No, it is not possible. beacuse when we create connection with postgre sql at time it's assembly is using Npgsql;
using NpgsqlTypes; and it have no any option for sturcture type. if it is connection with sql server than it is possible. and I can easily pass datatable. but in this case I have connection with postgresql not ms-sql.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? i am facing same issue